# Java POI - Creating Excel files with same parameters generates different files

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am doing a `JUnit` test that creates an Excel file, then compares it to a benchmark file.

However, when testing, my comparison to see if both files are equal always return false. So I tried a very sample code that creates the same file, but to different locations:

**Code**

```
@Test
public void testWrite() throws SQLException, IOException
{
    File createdFile = folder.newFile("myfile.xlsx");
    File createdFile2 = folder.newFile("myfile2.xlsx");

    // Same file created but using two different file names
    FormFile tester = new FormFile(createdFile, "Harvard");
    tester.write();

    tester = new FormFile(createdFile2, "Harvard");
    tester.write();

    // Always return false
    assertEquals(FileUtils.contentEquals(createdFile, createdFile2), true);
}

public class FormFile
{

    private File file;
    private String schoolName;

    public FormFile(File file, String schoolName)
    {
        this.file = file;
        this.schoolName = schoolName;
    }

    workbook = POIExcelFileProcessor.createWorkbook(FormFileTest.class.getResourceAsStream(FORM_FILE_TEMPLATE_FILENAME));

    // Code to modify the workbook

    POIExcelFileProcessor.writeWorkbook(workbook, file);
}

public class POIExcelFileProcessor
{

    public static Workbook createWorkbook(InputStream inputStream)
    {
        Workbook workbook = null;

        try
        {
            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return workbook;
    }

    public static void writeWorkbook(Workbook workbook, File outputFile)
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            workbook.write(fileOut);

            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
            workbook.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Even with using the same parameter (here the string "Harvard"), both files' content is still not identical and I have no idea why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think some excel file is "bitwise" equal to another excel file with the same content?

Comment: I am relatively new to programming, but I can only think of: Why wouldn't it? Does Excel add some other characters like time stamps or other non related characters?

Comment: I don't know, Excel files are using is a pretty closed format from Microsoft, I would read the file with POI and compare content cell by cell (+ header footer format etc if needed)

Comment: Thank your for your help. Please add this as an answer for me to select.

Comment: The `*.xlsx` format [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) is well documented and **not** closed. And surely it stores meta informations such as  document properties. Date and time when the file is created for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest spreadsheet you can create will have a created date timestamp. You can validate this:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class SimpleSheet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sh1 = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
        Row r = sh1.createRow(0);
        Cell c = r.createCell(0);
        c.setCellValue("Test");

        // Write the output to a file
        String file = "simple-poi.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
        wb.close();
        System.out.println("Generated: " + file);
    }

}
```

Run this code, and then rename the file to *.zip. You will be able to see the xml files. Look in docProps/core.xml you will then see the timestamp. Rename the two files you created with your code to .zip, then look at the same file in each archive. This is likely the only thing that is different between your two files.